# Exact formula of divisor problem

Tags: divisor-counting-function

given the sum of divisors of a function

$$ D(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{x}d (n) = x\log x + x(2\gamma-1) + \Delta(x)\ $$

then what is the EXACT formula of $ \Delta (x) $ not the O-notation but the EXACT power series correction to the Dirichlet's divisor problem

where could i find the exact term solution ? is it related (the term) to the Hardy voronoi formula involving the divisor function ? $ d(n) $

Comment: Related: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.5535&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Chapter 12 of Titchmarsh's The theory of the Riemann zeta-function may help you